# regular expression, extract substring from path

Tags: javascript, regex

Doing this in javascript.

I have path's like this: /p/BC3eKD-rX-w/

I have a pattern like this: `/\/p\/([\w-]+)\//g`

I am trying to extract "BC3eKD-rX-w" but it keeps matching the entire string.

I suck at regular expressions, have spent 2 hours reading and watching videos and am very frustrated.

Help?

Comment: Use the group you have, it holds only what you need.

Comment: @Filkolev Can you be more specific?

Comment: There's already an answer. Your expression matches everything and what you need is inside a group, surrounded by `()`. You can extract the contents of the matched group as per jehna1's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var exp = /\/p\/([\w-]+)\//g;
console.log(exp.exec("/p/BC3eKD-rX-w/")[1]);
```

Works fine with me.

Comment: I was using match. Why doesn't match return only the specified group?

Comment: Because of the `/g` flag. From [String.match documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): "If the regular expression includes the g flag ... **Captured groups are not returned.**"